# vba regex: how to extract exact recurring match at start, between, at the end of a string

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I'm trying with no luck to extract a recurring word inside a string using RegEx in Excel VBA.

Following an example:

I'm trying with no luck to extract a recurring word inside a string using RegEx in Excel VBA.

Following an example:

```
Sub RegExTest()

 Dim re As Object
 Dim el As Object
 Const strText As String = "Fld,Fld,Fld,Fld,Fld,aFld1,bFld,cFld,Fld"
 Debug.Print strText
 With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
  .Global = True
  .MultiLine = False
  .IgnoreCase = False
  .pattern = "(^Fld\,|\,Fld\,|\,Fld$)"
  If .Test(strText) Then
   Set re = .Execute(strText)
  End If
 End With
 For Each el In re
  Debug.Print el
 Next
End Sub

Result:
Fld,Fld,Fld,Fld,Fld,aFld1,bFld,cFld,Fld
Fld,
,Fld,
,Fld,
,Fld
```

The result that I get (4 elements) is not what I expect (6 elements).

I'm sure it is about a wrong pattern definition.

Can someone please help with the correct pattern?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please format your code properly; re-paste it in your question without all the line breaks, then highlight it all and press Ctrl+K.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion TylerH. I hope my code is now more readable than before.

Comment: Yep, much better, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that your matches are overlapping. By that I mean the comma in `Fld\,` is already matched, so your second Fld won't match `\,Fld\,`

[If you double up your commas you can see that you have the appropriate number of matches](https://regex101.com/r/qBlF62/12)

The solution here is to [use lookaheads to capture your matches.](https://regex101.com/r/qBlF62/14) If you absolutely need the trailing commas for some reason, just append them to the relevant matches.

Comment: hi emsimpson92, thanks very much for your simple and brilliant solution.